# Late 90's/early 2000's scifi horror movie: spec ops sent to underground lab, infectious goo takes over hosts; goo transform into spiders

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

In the movie, a special operations group gets sent to an underground lab where some kinda infectious goo gets loose where it can take over the host and control them just as if they were perfectly normal.

The practical effects I remember were pretty decent, with flesh peeling off a woman, while the CGI of the goo was kinda bad. There was one scene where the goo transforms into spiders to attack the special operations group, and it just looked pretty bad.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [Deep Evil](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389912/) from 2004 with Lorenzo Lamas.

> **An alien microbe lands in remote Siberia in the 1950's. In the year 2004, US scientist[s] working at a top secret underground lab in Alaska clone the microbe.** A garbled distress signal is heard from the lab just before a complete lock down of the facility. This is the last word sent out from the scientists. **A team of scientists and military personnel are in charge of finding out what went wrong.**

The alien slime infecting several members of the special team, faces peeling off and the slime creating a lot of small spiders at some point which attack them, it's all there. The effects are about what you'd expect from a small-budget flick; the 'slime' looks more like water. The trailer:

Comment: Bro you are amazing! Thats the one I've been looking for so long! Thank you very much and I hope your day is awesome!